# ruby-2.0, rails-4 no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

In the bin folder of my rails app, I have a script for polling the inbox of a gmail account for any received mail but this line **imap = Net::IMAP.new(config[:host], config[:port], true)** fails with **no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer**

This is a shotened form of the script

```
  #bin/mail_receiver.rb
  require File.join(File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)), '..', 'config', 'environment')
  require 'net/imap'
  require 'net/http'
  require 'rubygems'

  config = File.expand_path('../../config/initializers/load_imap_settings',  __FILE__)

  imap = Net::IMAP.new(config[:host], config[:port], true)
```

The **my_settings.yml** is loaded in **application.rb** before other **rails configuration** and I have confirmed in the console that they are available

```
#config/my_settings.yml
IMAP_HOST: 'imap.gmail.com'
IMAP_PORT: '993'
IMAP_USERNAME: 'xxxvvvyyy@gmail.com'
IMAP_PASSWORD: 'xxxvvvyyy'
```

I then make it available in initializer for use in the **mail_receiver.rb** script pasted earlier

```
#config/initializers/load_imap_settings.rb
ImapSettings =  { 
  host:  ENV['IMAP_HOST'], 
  port:  ENV['IMAP_PORT'], 
  username: ENV['IMAP_USERNAME'], 
 password: ENV['IMAP_PASSWORD'] 
}
```

In a rails console, I can do

```
config = ImapSettings
config[:host]
```

this will returns

```
'imap.gmail.com'
```

Similarly **config[:port]** or **config[:username]** or **config[:password]** all return the right values in the **rails console** with no error.

Comment: Try to provide `993` to `IMAP_PORT` without quotes ' in your setting file.

Comment: Thanks but I tried that before and it throws the error **no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String (TypeError)** when I run either the daemon  **ruby  bin/mail_receiver_ctl.rb  start** or **rails console**

Comment: if your post is any example of your code, i'd try checking for spelling mistakes :p

Comment: In your `mail_receiver.rb` file [File.expand_path](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-expand_path) returns string. Using string as `string[:something]` produced error `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)`. So you don't assign parameters in the string `config = File.expand_path('..`

Comment: Thanks, but what are the alternatives to use in place of **File.expand_path**, so as not to return a string. I will **Google** around and check through **Stackoverflow**, but if you have suggestions, they are welcome.

Comment: I think `require_relative 'load_imap_settings'` will work (you should cope with it path), after that you could assign `config` like `config = ImapSettings` as in console case. And then it should work as you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.expand_path` in your **bin/mail_receiver.rb** returns a string of path. This string assigned to `config` variable and when you call `config[:host]` or `config[:port]` ruby raise an error `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)` because it expected that for `String` there (inside of []) should be an Integer, or Range, or etc (you could see doc for it there http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

You should load your config from **config/initializers/load_imap_settings.rb** by `require_relative` and then assign hash of parameters `ImapSettings` to `confing` variable. Your code (in **bin/mail_receiver.rb**) then could be like this:

```
require_relative '../../config/initializers/load_imap_settings'
config = ImapSettings
imap = Net::IMAP.new(config[:host], config[:port], true)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time. The code fails at the **require_relative** line with bin/mail_receiver.rb:4:in `require_relative': **cannot load such file -- /home/action/workspace/config/initializers/load_imap_settings (LoadError)  
from bin/mail_receiver.rb:4:in `<main>'**

Comment: So, what is relative path of this file? `load_imap_settings.rb` I mean. You could put this path to `require_relative` then

Comment: I opened /bin/rails and saw that they used **require_relative '../config/boot'**, So adjusted the **require_relative** line to become, **require_relative '../config/initializers/load_imap_settings'**.

Comment: Though the error  of **no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer**, the script dies in the very next line when it tries ** imap.login(config[:username], config[:password])** without **error**, I know that because I added a **puts statement** underneath it to see it will appear in terminal and it didn't. It means we can't use the **imap** variable created with ** imap = Net::IMAP.new(config[:host], config[:port], true)**

Comment: So try to `p config` before `imap = ...` to be sure `config` is properly initialized.

Comment: **p "#{config}** returns **config is, {:host=>"imap.gmail.com", :port=>"993", :username=>"xxxvvv@gmail.com", :password=>"xxxvvv"}**. And **p "#{imap}" returns ** #<Net::IMAP:0x00000004a51730>**. I then did **a = imap.login(config[:username], config[:password])** and then **puts "#{a}"**, this returned nothing or it wasn't called.

Comment: So the problem now is how to use imap ;) There could be a lot of faults, starting form wrong password/login pair...

Comment: Yes I believe so. Thesame exact code was working when it was written and added to a rails 3.0 app. I just upgraded the app to rails 4, so I will look at **ruby's net/http** to see what has changed.